# ODE of an eccentric circle

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

How can we simplify the solution in:

```
DSolve[ {Sqrt[ 1 - (r[t] - T^2/r[t])^2/(2 a)^2]/(r[t] - T^2/r[t])/(2 a) == 
r'[t]/ r[t], r[0] == T}, r, t]
```

(r,t) are polar coordinates.

EDIT1:

Second order ODE in terms of $\psi, r, \theta $ which respectively are: angle between arc and radius vector and the polar coordinates. ( Constants T > a)

$$ \psi^{''}(s)= \dfrac{T^2 \cos \psi}{2 \,a \,r(s)^3} $$

$$ \dfrac {d \theta}{ds}=\dfrac{\sin \psi}{ r(s)} = \dfrac{1-T^2/a^2}{2 a} $$

$$ \dfrac {d r}{ds}=\cos \psi $$

Boundary Conditions:

$$ @ r= T, \psi(0) = \psi^{'}(0) =0 , \psi^{''}(0)= -1/ (2 a T). $$

Had no luck at start, trying..

Thanks in advance

EDIT 2:

Corrected errors, and now it works:

$$ \psi^{''}(s)= \dfrac{-T^2 \cos \psi}{ a \,r^3(s)} $$

Boundary Conditions:

$$ @ r= T, \psi(0) = 0, \,\psi^{'}(0) =1/a. $$

```
T = 4; a = 3; ri = T; smax = 2 Pi a;

    CIRC = {SI''[s] == -(T^2/a ) Cos[SI[s]]/R[s]^3, SI'[0] == 1/a, 
       SI[0] == 0, R'[s] == Cos[SI[s]], R[0] == ri, 
       TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], TH[0] == 0};

    NDSolve[CIRC, {SI, R, TH}, {s, 0, smax}];

    {si[u_], r[u_], th[u_]} = {SI[u], R[u], TH[u]} /. First[%];

    CENTRAL =  ParametricPlot[T { Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {v, .0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Purple, Thick}]

    ECC = ParametricPlot[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]]}, {s, .0, 
       smax}, PlotLabel -> ECCENTRIC_CIRCLE, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]

    Show[ECC, CENTRAL]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify the solution"? What do you get now; what would you like to get? For what purpose would you like to use the solution?

Comment: The solution is lengthy so did not transfer it here. Even if boundary condition is taken as  r[0]== r1, it is still unwieldy. The square root has two signs here, one for the convex and other concave part.   Reference is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398614/locus-of-points-on-a-rotating-line, where we can further show the result applies to two different parts of *same* curve or circle. Much appreciate any help to express it (r-t) form also.

Comment: Have you tried to use e.g. `ParametricNDSolve` to check that at least the equation is well-formed and it represents what you expect?

Comment: I tried NDSolve only. Even at r=r1 as BC it wont take off. At r=T ,it is a tougher start.

Comment: It occurs to me just now, I shall raise  it to second order and try, it often works.

Comment: It seems like you know the expected solution. Can you plug it in the formula to check?  Otherwise what makes you think the solution should have a simple form?

Comment: @george2079.  Seeing arctan and log in the solution I had hoped that these functions would form part of solution.. at least with some "nice" boundary conditions.

Comment: @george2079 Numerically it works, but the closed form is  still to come. I do not know the closed form solution, else I would not be posting this !.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in this question can be written as

```
eq = Sqrt[1 - (r[t] - T^2/r[t])^2/(2 a)^2]/(r[t] - T^2/r[t])/(2 a) == r'[t]/r[t];
DSolveValue[{eq, r[0] == T}, r[t], t] // FullSimplify
(* InverseFunction[((-Sqrt[-T^4] ArcTan[(2 a^2 + T^2 - #1^2)/
     Sqrt[4 a^2 #1^2 - (-T^2 + #1^2)^2]] + T^2 (-2 Log[#1] + 
     Log[-2 T^4 + 2 (2 a^2 + T^2) #1^2 + 
     2 Sqrt[-T^4] Sqrt[4 a^2 #1^2 - (-T^2 + #1^2)^2]])) 
     Sqrt[4 a^2 #1^2 - (-T^2 + #1^2)^2])/(
     2 Sqrt[-T^4] #1 Sqrt[(4 a^2 #1^2 - (-T^2 + #1^2)^2)/(a^2 #1^2)]) &][(
     t T^3 - 2 a (a T^3 ArcTan[a/T] + Sqrt[a^2 T^2] Sqrt[-T^4] (-2 Log[T] + 
     Log[4 (a^2 T^2 + Sqrt[a^2 T^2] Sqrt[-T^4])])))/(4 a T^3)] *)
```

which, as noted by the OP, is quite complicated.

Alternatively, this problem can be solved using `Integrate`, because the equation is first order and `t` does not appear explicitly.  Define

```
exp = eq[[1]] r[t] /. {r[t] -> a r0, T -> a T}
(* (r0 Sqrt[1 - (a r0 - (a T^2)/r0)^2/(4 a^2)])/(2 (a r0 - (a T^2)/r0)) *)
```

which replaces `r[t]` by `r0` and rescales `r0` and `t` by `a`.  Then, note the turning points of this expression.

```
Solve[exp == 0, r0]
(* {{r0 -> -1 - Sqrt[1 + T^2]}, {r0 -> 1 - Sqrt[1 + T^2]}, 
    {r0 -> -1 + Sqrt[1 + T^2]}, {r0 -> 1 + Sqrt[1 + T^2]}} *)
```

Since the minimum value of `r0` is given in the question as `T`, which we assume to be positive, the turning point of interest is the last one, `1 + Sqrt[1 + T^2]`, beyond which the integral will become complex.  Now, perform the integral in this region to obtain `t` as a function of `r`.

```
t = Integrate[1/exp, {r0, T, r}, Assumptions -> 0 < T < r < 1 + Sqrt[1 + T^2]]
(* -2 I a (2 Log[r] + Log[2 - 2 I T] + Log[-4 + 4 I T] - 
     Log[2 - r^2 + T^2 - I Sqrt[-r^4 - T^4 + 2 r^2 (2 + T^2)]] - 
     Log[2 T^4 - 2 r^2 (2 + T^2) + 2 I T^2 Sqrt[-r^4 - T^4 + 2 r^2 (2 + T^2)]]) *)
```

Although complicated, it is far less so that the `DSolve` expression.  Also, rescaling `t` by `a` eliminates `a` from the expression, leaving (the rescaled) `T` as the only free parameter.  As an example of the form of this solution, plot it with `T -> 1`.

```
ParametricPlot[{(t/a) /. {T -> 1}, r}, {r, 1, 4}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {"t/a", "r/a"}]
```

[image]

The curve stops at the turning point, `r/a = 1 + Sqrt[2]`.